# How to pass request over Django channels WebSocket and call Django view

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm working on a single page application with Django, and would like to use WebSockets, and therefore Channels. To keep things simple, I think I want to handle all server communication over a WebSocket alone, rather than adding XHR (XML HTTP Request) into the mix. I'm using channels from the get-go since there will be a lot of data pushed from the server to the client asynchronously.

With regular Django, a conventional request made to https://example.com/login or https://example.com/logout or whatever and the Django URL router will decide what view to send it to. Instead, I would like to have the user perform their action in the client, handle it with Javascript, and use the WebSocket to send the request to the server. Since I'm using Django-allauth, I would like to use the provided Django views to handle things like authentication. The server would then update the client with the necessary state information from the view.

**My question**: how can I process the data received over the WebSocket and submit the HTTP request to the Django view? My channels consumer would then take the rendered HTML and send it back to the client to update the page or section.

I can picture what would happen using XHR, but I'm trying to avoid mixing the two, unless someone can point out the usefulness in using XHR plus WebSockets...? I suppose another option is to use XHR for authentication and other client initiated requests, and use the WebSocket for asynchronously updating the client. Does this make any sense at all?

**Update**: It occurs to me that I could use `requests` from PyPi, and make an `sync_to_async` call to localhost using credentials I received over the WebSocket. However, this would require me to then handle the session data and send it back to the client. This seems like a lot more work. That said, I could maintain the sessions themselves on the server and just associate them with the WebSocket connection itself. Since I'm using a secure WebSocket `wss://` is there any possibility for hijacking the WebSocket connection?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this project](https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework) that gives the ability to process a channels websocket request using Django Rest Framework views. You can try to adapt it to a normal Django view.

**EDIT**: I am quoting the following part of the DCRF docs in response to @hobs comments:

> Using your normal views over a websocket connection
>
> ```
> from djangochannelsrestframework.consumers import view_as_consumer
>
> application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
>     "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
>         URLRouter([
>             url(r"^front(end)/$", view_as_consumer(YourDjangoView)),
>         ])
>     ),
>  })
> ```
>
> In this situation if your view needs to read the GET query string
> values you can provides these using the query option. And if the view
> method reads parameters from the URL you can provides these with the
> parameters.

@hobs if you have a problem with the naming of the package or the functionality is not working as intended, please take it up with the developers on Github using their issue tracker.

Comment: This does not create REST HTTP views, it is just another way to create Websocket consumers (WS:// endpoints) using code style and objects that look a little like the objects and functions in DRF.

Comment: I do not think that `djangochannelsrestframework` does what the OP wants. It does not relay a websocket consumer on to a DRF endpoint request or internal API call. The OP would have to issue an HTTP requests from within their channels/websocket consumers, whether or not they used your package djangochannelsrestframework (DCRF). DCRF is poorly-named. I have the same requirements as the OP and DCRF is not helpful for that (I don't see how to use it to accomplish the OP's needs). If you do, please provide a Django `views.py` example.

Comment: @hobs Please know that because you do not know how to accomplish the task does not mean it cannot be done. I have referenced the part of the DCRF package docs that clearly describes how to do that. And no, it is not my package, I was just trying to help the OP solve his issue. You have a Django view `ViewA` that you'd like to use and process a WS request and you wrap it in the `view_as_consumer` as shown in the docs I linked and that is it. The WS request is routed to a handler generated from your `ViewA`. If you have trouble using the package, ask a separate question and you will get answers.

Comment: I think you're right. Your example does seem like it would do what the OP wants. I'll test it.